# Ease-out Using setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, settimeout

I am attempting to create a slot machine type animation in which a list of emails will be cycled through. I would like the animation to start off fast but get progressively slower and slower until it stops. How would you recommend that I do something like this? I am currently doing something like:

```
$(function(){

  wait = 1;
  threshold = 100;
  timer = setTimeout(swap_email,wait);

});

function swap_email() {

  wait = wait + 1;

  if(threshold <= wait) {

    // Update the email div....
    timer = setTimeout(swap_email, wait);   

  }

  else {

    // We're done!        

  }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easing/tweening is a function of time. You tell your function how much time has passed, and it tells you how much distance has been traveled.

I use the following equation for 99% of the JS animation I do:

```
function simple_easing(how_much_time_has_passed) {
    return (1 - Math.cos(how_much_time_has_passed * Math.PI)) / 2;
}
```

I don't know why it works. I didn't try to understand the mathematics behind it.

But the above equation makes a lot of assumptions about how you're animating. The `how_much_time_has_passed` argument needs to be a decimal between 0 and 1; it also *returns* a decimal between 0 and 1, which is pretty much useless on its own (unless you're animating opacity).

When this function returns the `how_much` value, you'll need to do this to it:

```
current_value = start_value + total_distance * how_much;
```

...Which means that you'd have to start keeping track of other stuff that wasn't in your original example.

### Further Reading

[Robert Penner's awesome chapter about tweening equations from his awesome book.](http://www.robertpenner.com/easing/penner_chapter7_tweening.pdf)

---

**EDIT:** Or, you could just use a jQuery plugin.

Comment: That mathematics of yours looks like this: [(1 - cos(x)) / 2](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281+-+cos%28x%29%29+%2F+2). When pi < `how_much_time_has_passed` < 2*pi the result from `simple_easing()` will start decreasing towards 0. Correct me if I'm wrong!

Comment: @afEkenholm That goes to show you just how much I understand the equation. I'll look the sucker up and edit my answer.

Comment: you don't need mathematics. look at this graph and imagine x>0. you'll understand it ( http://bit.ly/WTgw1F )

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its help you:

```
var Timer = {
  threshold: 5000,
  wait: 1000,

  Start: function () {
    var _this = this;
    setTimeout(function () { _this.Swap(); }, _this.wait);
  },

  Swap: function () {
    this.wait += 1000;
    if (this.threshold > this.wait) {
      alert('next');
      this.Start();
    } else {
      alert('stop');
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: For start execute: Timer.Start();

Comment: @afEkenholm, it won't be linear. See `this.wait += 1000;`. Interesting approach, not useful in all circumstances. But interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Use the  [jQuery easing plugin](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/) and all the heavy lifting has been done for you in a single include ;)

Comment: I think he wants to change the currently visible e-mail address to another using an exponentially longer delay between each swap. Right?

Comment: @Kyle: What i meant was: plugin gives your all the math your need to do the easing, all you need to do now is to use that math for your swap function. I'm on my way to bed atm, so i don't have time to write up and example.. hope it's a little useful anyway.